# Excel - switch column/row but no transpose

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a few columns representing years. I want to make a single column named e.g. "Year" with years and second "Value" for values. Something like this:

[image]

Comment: You are looking for UnPivot, or flatten: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20541905/convert-matrix-to-3-column-table-reverse-pivot-unpivot-flatten-normal

Comment: Yup, Unpivot seems fine, but how to deal with it, when i have some other columns on left side?

Answer (score 0):

Formula in `A6`:

```
=OFFSET($A$2,INT((ROW(A6)-ROW(A$6))/(COLUMNS($A$1:$D$1)-1)),)
```

Formula in `B6`:

```
=OFFSET($B$1,,MOD(ROW(A6)-ROW(A$6),COLUMNS($A$1:$D$1)-1))
```

Formula in `C6`:

```
=OFFSET($B$2,INT((ROW(A6)-ROW(A$6))/(COLUMNS($A$1:$D$1)-1)),MOD(ROW(A6)-ROW(A$6),COLUMNS($A$1:$D$1)-1))
```

Copy/paste down to fill `A6:C11`:

[image]